# php soap client - Could not connect to host

Tags: php, soap-client

I am trying to make a SOAP call with SoapClient in PHP 7.0 but I run into this error:

**Could not connect to host**

The code is as follow:

```
$requestParams = array('passwordWSRequest' => array(
    'AppID' => 'testaim',
    'Query' => 'Object=ttms_04801053',
    'Safe'=>'Safe'
));
$opts = array(
    'ssl' => array('ciphers'=>'RC4-SHA', 'verify_peer'=>false, 'verify_peer_name'=>false, 'allow_self_signed' => true)
);
$params = array ('encoding' => 'UTF-8', 
    'verifypeer' => false, 
    'verifyhost' => false, 
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 
    'trace' => 1, 
    'exceptions' => 1, 
    "connection_timeout" => 180, 
    'stream_context' => $opts
);
$client = new SoapClient('AIM_Collaudo.wsdl', $params);
$response = $client->__soapCall("GetPassword",$requestParams);
```

The WSDL is as follow:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="https://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" targetNamespace="https://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="https://tempuri.org/">
      <s:element name="GetPassword">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="passwordWSRequest" type="tns:PasswordRequest" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="PasswordRequest">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AppID" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Safe" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Folder" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Object" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UserName" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Address" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Database" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PolicyID" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="FailRequestOnPasswordChange" type="s:boolean" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Reason" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" default="30" name="ConnectionTimeout" type="s:int" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Query" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="QueryFormat" nillable="true" type="tns:PasswordQueryFormat" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Attributes" type="tns:ArrayOfKeyAndValue" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:simpleType name="PasswordQueryFormat">
        <s:restriction base="s:string">
          <s:enumeration value="Exact" />
          <s:enumeration value="Regexp" />
        </s:restriction>
      </s:simpleType>
      <s:complexType name="ArrayOfKeyAndValue">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="KeyAndValue" nillable="true" type="tns:KeyAndValue" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="KeyAndValue">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="key" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="value" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:element name="GetPasswordResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetPasswordResult" type="tns:PasswordResponse" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="PasswordResponse">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Content" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UserName" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Address" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Database" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PolicyID" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Properties" type="tns:ArrayOfKeyAndValue" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="GetPasswordSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetPassword" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetPasswordSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetPasswordResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="AIMServiceSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetPassword">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetPasswordSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetPasswordSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="AIMServiceSoap" type="tns:AIMServiceSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetPassword">
      <soap:operation soapAction="https://tempuri.org/GetPassword" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="AIMServiceSoap12" type="tns:AIMServiceSoap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetPassword">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="https://tempuri.org/GetPassword" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="AIMService">
    <wsdl:port name="AIMServiceSoap" binding="tns:AIMServiceSoap">
      <soap:address location="https://mysoapserver/AIMWebservice/v1.1/AIM.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="AIMServiceSoap12" binding="tns:AIMServiceSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="https://mysoapserver/AIMWebservice/v1.1/AIM.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The getLastRequest from the client ($client->__getLastRequest()) is:

```
   REQUEST:
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="https://tempuri.org/"> 
   <env:Body><ns1:GetPassword/></env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

Someone can help? How can I know what host it is trying to connect? Do I need to add this information somewhere?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't it `<soap:address location="https://mysoapserver/AIMWebservice/v1.1/AIM.asmx" />` in the bottom of the wsdl?

Comment: I guess it is, but the server is reachable and working fine...